What is the expectation of this power series of random variables?
Let $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be iid random variables distributed uniformly in $(-1, 1)$, and consider, for some fixed $r \in [0, 1)$, the limiting random variable
$$ X = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n a_k r^k \,. $$
Question: What is the expectation
$$ \mathbb{E}[\log|X|] \, ? $$
Progress so far: I have (I think) proven that
$$ \mathbb{E}[\log|X|] = \mathbb{E}[(1+rX)\log|1+rX|] - 1 \,, $$
which we can Taylor-expand to get an expression for the expectation in terms of the moments $\mathbb{E}[X^k]$. I can show that $\mathbb{E}[X^k] = 0$ for all odd $k$ and
$$ \mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[a_0^2] \sum_{k=0}^\infty r^{2k} = \frac{1}{3(1-r^2)} \,, $$
while
$$ \mathbb{E}[X^4] = \frac{1}{5(1-r^4)} + \frac{1}{3}\left( \frac{1}{(1-r^2)^2} - \frac{1}{1-r^4} \right) \,, $$
and have attempted to compute higher moments, but have not found a closed-form expression for them. Any ideas / hints / suggestions?

Simulation suggests that what you have done so far looks highly plausible.

It also suggests that $E[\log|X|]$ is close to $-1$ for $r$ close to $0$ (note $-\log|X| \sim Exp(1)$ when $r=0$), and larger (less negative, and eventually positive) for $r$ closer to $\pm1$.

I can show that the MGF of $X$ takes the form $$\mathbb{E}[\exp(sX)]=\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2n}B_{2n}}{(2n)!(2n)}\frac{z^{2n}}{1-r^{2n}}\right),$$ where $B_\bullet$ are the Bernoulli numbers. This can be used to find any $p$-moment of $X$ for small $p$, but the computation quickly goes out of control as $p$ grows. Also, it follows that $$\mathbb{E}[\log|X|]=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-z}-\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\operatorname{sinc}(r^k z)}{z},\mathrm{d}z,$$ although I am not sure if a nice closed-form exists or not.

Wow! Thanks for this. I will try proving your result myself before asking for further help, but one question: what is $z$ in the MGF you provide?

@smalldog, Oops, I intended $z$ to be the variable for the MGF, so $z$ should be $s$. Sorry for the confusion! Also, as for the proof, the following relations would help: $$\mathbb{E}[\exp(sX)]=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[\exp(sr^k a)]=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\operatorname{sinhc}(r^ks)=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\prod_{l=1}^{\infty}\cosh\left(\frac{sr^k}{2^l}\right).$$ The Bernoulli numbers appear when we try to Taylor-expand $\log\cosh(z)$.

@SangchulLee I had the same expression for the MGF as your product of $\text{sinhc}(r^ks)$ terms, but can't quite get from there to your expression for $\mathbb{E}[\log |X|]$... Any hints? Also, do you mean sinc or sinhc in the latter expectation?

Indeed the integral representation for $\mathbb{E}[\log|X|]$ is not so trivial to derive. This hinges on the following Frullani-type integral: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-z}-e^{ixz}}{z},\mathrm{d}z=\log|x|-\frac{i\pi}{2}\operatorname{sgn}(x).$$ The imaginary part cancels out in our case because the distribution of $X$ is symmetric.

Very interesting, I had never come across this integral! Thanks immensely for your help. The question of a closed-form solution is still open, but this is great progress, would you like to post an answer so I can accept it?
